# JavaFX canvas GraphicsContext.drawImage enormous lag

Tags: java, canvas, javafx

I am making a map editor using JavaFX for the UI and a custom canvas to draw the component where the user would paint the map.

This is the canvas component I am embedding in my map editor

```
public class EditorEngine extends Canvas {

    public Level level;
    public MouseHandler mouse;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public EditorEngine(Level level, ReadOnlyDoubleProperty widthProperty, ReadOnlyDoubleProperty heightProperty) {
        super(widthProperty.getValue(), heightProperty.getValue());

        this.level = level;
        level.engine = this;
        this.widthProperty().bind(widthProperty);
        this.heightProperty().bind(heightProperty);
        this.mouse = new MouseHandler(this);

        Duration frameDuration = Duration.millis(1000 / 42);

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        KeyFrame frame = new KeyFrame(frameDuration, new EventHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Event event) {
                update();
                render();
            }
        });

        new Timeline(60).setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        TimelineBuilder.create().cycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE).keyFrames(frame).build().play();
    }

    public int tick = 0;

    public void update() {
        tick++;

        if (level != null) {
            level.update();
        }

        mouse.update();
    }

    public void render() {
        GraphicsContext g = getGraphicsContext2D();

        g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.fillRect(mouse.mx - 5, mouse.my - 5, 10, 10); //for testing and stuff

        if (level != null) {
            level.render(g);
        }

    }
}
```

But this is not where the problem is occuring. Take a look at my Level.draw method

```
public void render(GraphicsContext g) {
    for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) {
            if (getTile(i, j) == null) continue;

            Tileset t = Project.current.world.getTileset(tiles[j * w + i].tileset);

            if (t.sprite != null) {
                g.drawImage(t.sprite.get(), tiles[index(i, j)].sprite % t.w, tiles[index(i, j)].sprite / t.w, 16, 16, i * 16, j * 16, 16, 16);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Warning: Tileset.sprite == null!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This being the faulty line

```
g.drawImage(t.sprite.get(), tiles[index(i, j)].sprite % t.w, tiles[index(i, j)].sprite / t.w, 16, 16, i * 16, j * 16, 16, 16);
```

Calling this for two or three tiles will lag a bit and anywhere near 5+ tiles completely freezes up the application. I am 100% that it is the problem because it runs 100% fine without that line but as soon as it add it back (in debug mode) and save, software immediately freezes.

Would anyone have any idea why this is occuring? Thanks

Comment: There were performance fixes for [Java 8](https://jdk8.java.net/).  Does it work any better with Java 8?  Also does running a [graphicsContext.clearRect()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#clearRect%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double%29) (or `fillRect`) method before rendering each frame help with performance?

Comment: I'm actually using Java 8 right now and I am already using clearrect before rendering anything as you can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. This was a mistake on my part, something I completely overlooked. t.sprite is my own LazySprite class, a sprite that is loaded from the HDD only when it is needed. It turns out that I forgot to set its boolean "initialized" to true after it was loaded, so it kept loading the tileset from my HDD every single frames.